# Best way to get info out of dictionary

Tags: python

I am struggling to wrap my head around the best way to get the Title, Artist Name out the following list.

```
{'status': 'ok', 'results': [{'score': 0.94222, 'id': 'ca222fc1-d1ed-4c30-b21f-eb533cc909aa', 'recordings': [{'artists': [{'id': '84dc4f23-c0b8-4fe1-bbca-a3993ddc8fc2', 'name': 'Primus'}], 'id': '2f6227ba-e061-48b2-a700-15e209ed3650', 'title': 'Wynona’s Big Brown Beaver', 'duration': 264}, {'artists': [{'id': '84dc4f23-c0b8-4fe1-bbca-a3993ddc8fc2', 'name': 'Primus'}], 'id': '520ebd07-d12c-429c-a137-19d13303a706', 'title': 'Wynona’s Big Brown Beaver', 'duration': 261}, {'artists': [{'id': '84dc4f23-c0b8-4fe1-bbca-a3993ddc8fc2', 'name': 'Primus'}], 'id': '757439ce-58b1-4808-af3b-3b90092890c1', 'title': 'Wynona’s Big Brown Beaver', 'duration': 262}, {'artists': [{'id': '84dc4f23-c0b8-4fe1-bbca-a3993ddc8fc2', 'name': 'Primus'}], 'id': 'a432eaa4-e5bb-414a-9595-cdaa46d48d6e', 'title': 'Wynona’s Big Brown Beaver', 'duration': 264}, {'artists': [{'id': '84dc4f23-c0b8-4fe1-bbca-a3993ddc8fc2', 'name': 'Primus'}], 'id': 'c344a3f9-1755-4f1b-b227-8a5918713466', 'title': 'Wynona’s Big Brown Beaver', 'duration': 261}, {'artists': [{'id': '84dc4f23-c0b8-4fe1-bbca-a3993ddc8fc2', 'name': 'Primus'}], 'id': 'e658eb35-9d15-45d8-965c-1abcb19c8bc9', 'title': 'Wynona’s Big Brown Beaver', 'duration': 264}]}]}
```

I am using acoustic.match to match songs and the above list is what is returned.

There has to be something more elegant than how I am doing it which is:

```
print(song['results'][0]['recordings'][0]['title'])
```

Any pointers?

*****Edit*****
So - in further review - there is example code that I am trying to follow - but can't seem to get it to work.

```
for score, recording_id, title, artist in acoustid.match(apikey, path):
```

acoustid.match returns the dictionary/list above.

Comment: A dictionary is a key-value pair.  To get the value, you give it the key.  That is the only way to get information from a dictionary.  If that does not suit you, use a different data structure

Comment: You can make it more readable by using intermediate variables. `first_song_results = song['results'][0]; recordings = first_song_results['recordings'][0]; recordings['title']`

Comment: Note also that a dictionary like this is made to pack a lot of information that you probably want to loop over. `for song in song['results']: for recording in song['recordings']: print(recording['title'])`

Comment: I get a syntax error when I paste the above into a python shell. Also when I try to assign the above in a python shell.

Comment: @rajah9: I get "Wynona’s Big Brown Beaver." Not sure if that's better or worse...

Answer (score 2):

If the dict is bothering you, you may want to convert it to a class.

```
class Music():

    def __init__(self, song):
        self.title = song['results'][0]['recordings'][0]['title']
        self.artist = song['results'][0]['recordings'][0]['artist'][0]['name']
        # and so on and so forth


new_song = Music(song)
>>> print new_song.artist
Primus
>>> print new_song.title
Wynona’s Big Brown Beaver
```

Answer (score 0):

The data which you getting is mix of dict and list. Since list can only be accessed via index I dont think there could be a better way of doing it unless you preprocess your data to remove that extra nested list.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13022108)

Comment: There is no link in my post, What are you referring to?